# react-navigation change duration of goBack transition

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hopefully this is a fairly straightforward question, but I'm having issues with a transition in my react-native application using react-navigation. I'd like to resolve them by simply removing the transition on goBack for this particular screen.

Is there a way to change the duration of goBack?

----EDIT----

My current transitionConfig:

```
transitionConfig: ({ scene }) => {
  const params = scene.route.params || {};

  if (params.skipAnimation) {
    return {
      transitionSpec: {
        duration: 0,
        timing: Animated.timing,
      },
    };
  }

  return {};
},
```

When I'd like my transition to have no animation, I do `navigation.navigate` and add the param `skipAnimation: true` to the navigate call. This works for that navigation transition, HOWEVER, the that duration is *not* observed by the goBack transition, and the `goBack()` function does not accept params. Thus, I'm seeking to find if there's a way to force the duration for the goBack transition.

There's a specific screen I want to simply appear/disappear without any animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass config to your navigator like this,

```
createStackNavigator(
  {
  ....//your routes
  },
  {
    transitionConfig: () => {
      return {
        transitionSpec: {
          duration: 1000
        }
      };
    },
    initialRouteName: "Your first screen"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:

for back button, use backhandler..

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Your Screen'); //this will not push new screen if you have visited that screen and just behave like normal go back
 }
```

}

Comment: Hello, this seems only to affect the transition going INTO a screen, but when I goBack FROM the screen, the normal duration is present.

Comment: Right, but when using `navigation.navigate` if the action is to "behave like a normal goBack" the duration cannot be set for that animation. That's what I'm attempting to solve. I'll throw in some code above to help